# TRY CATCH + Error Storing is letting the Procedure Run

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an error tracking procedure, the idea being if an error occurring from either the proc or the data quality would trigger either a standard or custom error, stop the stored procedure, and store the error. However, my current script is storing the error perfectly fine, but is not stopping the proc from running.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
DECLARE @ErrorProcedure        VARCHAR(128)  
DECLARE @ErrorMessage          VARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity         INT  
DECLARE @ErrorCreateDate       DATETIME2                    ---DECLARED VARIABLES THAT ARE BEING PASSED ON TO THE ERROR INSERT FUNCTION
DECLARE @ErrorCode             INT 
DECLARE @ErrorUserName         VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @ErrorLine             INT  
DECLARE @ErrorParameter        VARCHAR(750)
DECLARE @ErrorReportName       VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @ErrorTrackingID       INT
DECLARE @TriggerParameter      INT

SET @ErrorParameter = 'no parameters'

 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BEGIN TRY
  SELECT 1/0;
   -- THROW 50000,'You tried to divide.', 1;
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH


   --SET @ParamDetails = ' @Var1 = ' + CAST(ISNULL(@Var1, 'NULL') AS VARCHAR(256))
   --                 + ',@Var2 = ' + CAST(ISNULL(@Var2, 'NULL') AS VARCHAR(256))
   --                 + ',@Var3 = ' + CAST(ISNULL(@Var3, 'NULL') AS VARCHAR(256))

  --EXEC dbo.ErrorTrackingInsert @ParamDetails,@ErrorTrackingId OUTPUT
  --select @ErrorTrackingId
  --RAISERROR('You tried to divide by 0.', 16, 1);


  SELECT  ---THIS IS WHERE WE STORE THE ERROR VALUES CREATED IN THE TRY ABOVE
       @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE()  ,  
       @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()      ,
       @ErrorCode = ERROR_NUMBER()          ,                                                                   --- This Section allows us to store the error inputs into the variable
       @ErrorSeverity= ERROR_SEVERITY()     ,   
       @ErrorCreateDate  = SYSDATETIME()    , 
       @ErrorUserName = SUSER_SNAME()       , 
       @ErrorLine= ERROR_LINE()   

       EXEC [dbo].[TestErrorInsert] @ErrorProcedure , 
                 @ErrorMessage   ,
                 @ErrorSeverity  ,
                 @ErrorCreateDate,
                 @ErrorCode      ,
                 @ErrorUserName  ,
                 @ErrorLine      ,
                 @ErrorParameter ,
                 @ErrorReportName,
                 @ErrorTrackingID OUTPUT


 END CATCH
END
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: T-SQL Microsoft Server

Comment: That didnt work, but I was able to solve it. I used the `PRINT @ErrorMessage; Throw; Return` right before end catch and it worked. So it was in line with yours as well

Answer (score 0):

Hello to anyone finding a similar problem.

If you add to right before the `END CATCH` this string of code:

```
PRINT @ErrorMessage;
THROW;
RETURN
```

Comment: You might be sadly disappointed in your attempt to "store the error". Generally, most errors occur within a transaction - an error will (or should) trigger a rollback which will also remove your "storage" attempt. Erland discusses [this (error handling)](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) in great detail.

Comment: It's working perfect at the moment, I have heard of it triggering a roll back but have not run into the issue so far. We'll see once we move these functionalities into production.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [XACT_ABORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is off.  If you `SET XACT_ABORT ON`, the current batch will be terminated, and any open transactions will be terminated.

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
>   run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
>
> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL
>   statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction
>   continues processing. Depending upon the severity of the error, the
>   entire transaction may be rolled back even when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF.
>   OFF is the default setting.

The top of the linked article above mentions using THROW instead of RAISERROR in new apps:

> The THROW statement honors SET XACT_ABORT. RAISERROR does not. New
>   applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.